# Validating Windows access token on a different computer

Tags: c++, windows, token

I am developing a client/server application (client and server are both written in C++ and running on Windows computers).
I need to authorize the current user of the client computer on the server computer, but without the necessity for the user to enter his password.

In Windows you have the access tokens of the currently running process. You can also check which user is assigned to that token and in which groups it is, etc.
I would like to send that token to my server application and validate it there against the domain controller. Is something like this possible in Windows?

I imagine a scenario like that: The client application generates a token, which can be verified against the domain controller that the token was generated by that user and is valid for some minutes. Then the token will be serialized and send to my server application (i. e. via REST API). Then my server deserializes that token and uses a Windows API to validate that generated token against the domain controller. The domain controller also provides additional information like the user name included in that token.

Is that possible? I found something like "Windows Identity Foundation" and "AuthZ" API, but it doesn't seem to fit?

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact thing. In other answers on this site WIF's `WindowsIdentity.getCurrent()` function returns a token that is  "pre-verified" which is total non-sense. A security token should contain a digital signature of the issuer so that the token can be verified by anything that obtains it to have come from the issuer. WIF and ADFS are advertised everywhere to be "claims based and federated" but forgot to implement the ability for an application to verify any claim made to it. My bet is, windows is not currently capable of doing what you are describing.

Comment: Meanwhile I found a solution:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/

In this apache module the Kerberos validation via NTLM/Negotiate is implemented.
I checked what this module does and implemented the same functions.

Unfortunately the token seems to be restricted. But at least you know it is valid and you can read the user name and the user group membership.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it, ADFS and NTLM support this, but check out [this article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introduction-to-windows-tokens-for-security-practitioners) its a great read on how to do it.

[image: shared token]

Comment: Your article says precisely the opposite
"The user’s logon session is unique to their workstation... and they cannot simply send their access token over the wire. The token would be meaningless as it does not correspond to a valid logon session on the remote host. ...this authentication mechanism [is a] target for replay attacks." To which they talk about using Kerberos to create a network login instead which and I quote "Network logins do not cache credentials... therefore... cannot use... token to authenticate to another remote host. This is.... the ‘double hop’ problem."